# Magento CMS URL_KEY not working. Ends up empty

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a big issue with magento. I can't create new CMS pages. I can create one page which will have empty "Url key" as it wont generate any. If i enter one manually when creating the page, it won't save it either.

The second page i try creating generates the error as in the picture below ofcourse.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUDjC.jpg

This happen after upgrading from version 1.8 -> 1.9.

Comment: Have you checked your system and exception logs for errors?

Comment: Yeah i did and there is nothing in there about this. :/

Comment: How about your web server error logs?

Comment: How customized is your Magento set?

Comment: This might help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62181/problem-programmatically-saving-url-key-for-category